# Visual Studio Get Auto Increment Product Version

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to add a Product Version to a Form.`[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]`

```
   string version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

This is the solution I found, and which will work. But the Version will be like "1.0.6262.26540".
Can I change the Rule or can I get the Publish Version which Visual Studio generates programmatically? 
[image: Publish Version generated by Visual Studio]

Comment: [Application.ProductVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.application.productversion(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: Thats not what I am looking for. Application.ProductVersion will have the same output: 1.0.6262.26540. I want to Version to be 1.0.0.12

Comment: Can you look into AssemblyInfo.cs and check what is there for Version?

Comment: like i said in my post: [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]

Comment: Ah, right. In that case: "The default build number increments daily. The default revision number is random." [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx) Have you tried changing "1.0.*" to "1.0.0.12" ? Then republish and check outcome?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString()`. However, this will only work if you are running a version of your program that was installed by the ClickOnce publisher installer (`ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed` returns `true`).

When you start the compiled assembly directly (e.g. during debugging), you will  get an `InvalidDeploymentException` when trying to access the `CurrentDeployment` property. To safeguard against this, you can use something like this:

```
string CurrentVersion
{
    get
    {
        return ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed
            ? ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString()
            : "1.0.0.0"; // Fallback version string, or retrieve from assembly as in your question
    }
}
```

If you are **not** using the ClickOnce Publish function to distribute your software I am not sure that you can expect to access the "Publish Version".

Comment: I am using the ClickOnce Publisher :D but I cant find ApplicationDeployment, which namespace i have to add?

Comment: @itskajo [System.Deployment.Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyAssemblyInfoPatcher
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                string path = args[0].ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Current App version is set to: {0}", path));
                string now_date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd.HHmm");
                if (File.Exists(path))
                {
                    string _AssemblyVersion = string.Empty;
                    string _AssemblyFileVersion = string.Empty;

                    var lines = File.ReadLines(string.Format(path));
                    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        if (lines.ElementAt(i).ToString().StartsWith("[assembly: AssemblyVersion"))
                        {
                            _AssemblyVersion = lines.ElementAt(i).ToString();
                        }
                        else if (lines.ElementAt(i).ToString().StartsWith("[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion"))
                        {
                            _AssemblyFileVersion = lines.ElementAt(i).ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    string _replace_assembly = File.ReadAllText(path);

                    if (_AssemblyVersion != string.Empty)
                    {
                        _replace_assembly = _replace_assembly.Replace(_AssemblyVersion, string.Format("[assembly: AssemblyVersion(\"{0}\")]", now_date));
                    }
                    if (_AssemblyFileVersion != string.Empty)
                    {
                        _replace_assembly = _replace_assembly.Replace(_AssemblyFileVersion, string.Format("[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion(\"{0}\")]", now_date));
                    }

                    File.WriteAllText(path, _replace_assembly);
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Above the programs code, you can create a console application and in Project Properties > Build Events, add a "Pre-build event command line" like this: "D:\SomePath\MyAssemblyInfoPatcher.exe" "$(ProjectDir)Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"